# Manually set numbering on Nikon D7000

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, filenames

Let's say the most recent image on the camera was numbered DSC_1000.NEF, and I want the next image to be numbered DSC_1234.NEF. How would I accomplish this?

I've tried a lot of things, but none of them work. For example, I've tried putting the SD card into a computer and renaming it DSC_1233.NEF, but after I return it to the camera and take a picture, it creates a new folder and continues the old numbering at DSC_1001.NEF.

Now, there are ways to increment the number one by one. Obviously you could just fire off a bunch of shots, but I don't want to waste actuations just to advance a number. Another is to open up a picture in the Retouch menu and save it, but I'm not going to sit there doing that manually hundreds or thousands of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by setting option **d8** in the Custom Menu to **RESET**, then doing your renaming on the computer trick. From the D7000 manual:

> RESET: As for On, except that the next photograph taken is assigned a file number by 
>   adding one to the largest file number in the current folder. If the folder is empty, 
>   file numbering is reset to 0001.

Comment: Thanks! I also have a D5100, and I did most of my searching over this issue back then and assumed that the D7000 would be just the same. It seems that the equivalent option, d3, does the following: "The numbering will be reset to 0001 for the next shot and then the numbering will continue with option 'on'." Is there no hope for the D5100?

Comment: It doesn't sound like the kind of thing they'd change with a firmware update or the like, so probably not, no.